# Jenkins with PM2 - issue with possibility to enter to the running server

Tags: jenkins, deployment, centos, pm2

Got issue regarding pm2. Right now I've got a Jenkins that should build an application during each commit. Everything works fine. In the pipeline, Jenkins should start a server with PM2.

Right now Jenkins has got access to pm2 and everything works smoothly. Unfortunately, the issue is when I'm on the user "test" and write `pm2 ls` - I see an empty list of processes.

And this is causing some issues because my nginx is not able to detect working applications so I receive "502".

In Jenkins, when I write `pm2 ls` I see that process works fine. Also tried it with `sudo pm2 start` and then in the console `sudo pm2 ls` - in such case, I see the process, but in the jenkins, the status is `success` but in the terminal - it's errored` and also nginx does not see that server.

Also important information, that when I type the command:
 `pm2 start "npm run start-prod" --name myAppName` - the process is seen in `test` user and the nginx also works fine.

Do you know how can I settle the PM2 with Jenkins and set the process to be "global" and seen by the "test" user?

Answer (score 0):

To make it - I should use --watch flag in pm2. That allow me to watch the changes in the file and run it via *test* user.